# How do you change login options on start screen in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04

Not sure why but after I loaded Ubuntu on an old Acer (only OS) it asks to confirm user name before accepting PW.  As I'm the only user how do I stop being offered this option and just enter PW?

Comment: Did you configure any thing related to it??

Comment: Not that I know of, I presume I miss-keyed at the critical point during installation.

Comment: Ok.. are  you using default display manager that is gdm3? can you share a screen shot where it is asking for confirmation of user? It will help to understand better and may have a quick solution.

Comment: is it prompting like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPsJk.png

Comment: Sorry can't see how to add screen shot.  It comes up with my user name in the box but says "Not listed?" below that.  I am the only user, never been another user since loading.  Don't know what display manager is but is certainly Ubuntu default.

Comment: That's the default behaviour.. you ignore "Not listed?" text and click on the username to enter pw.

Comment: Thank you, I've never seen that before, just typed PW directly without having to click or enter.  If i's default I'll learn to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the default option for gdm3 (GNOME DISPLAY MANAGER)

[image]

In some very rare cases it is possible to login as special user case like `gdm` user for example.. thats why the option is showing "Not listed" to allow by entering user name and then password.

you can verify this by accessing to accounts directory

```
nautilus /var/lib/AccountsService/users
```

[image]

Observe that my own account has last line "false" this means this users shows in gdm login screen and other two with "true" this means they will not be shown but it may be possible to login to those users in very special and rare cases.. you can consider them they will never be used.